# Error with filter in react js Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, filter

Iam using filter to filter an array of objects which I fetch it from api by axios and store it in redux state it works well for mapping but with filter it gives this error Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined in reactjs

```
    class ProductsList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
      
       this.state = {
          search : '' 

        } 
    }

   searchUpdate(event) {
   this.setState({search: event.target.value.substr(0,20)})
} 

async componentDidMount() {

  
  const { fetchProducts } = this.props;
  
  await fetchProducts();
  

  }
  async componentDidUpdate() {
    
  const { fetchProducts } = this.props;
  
  await fetchProducts();
    
   }





    render() {
    //The problem with this filter method however if I don't use it it works will
let productsFiltered = this.props.products.filter((itemProduct)=>{
  return  itemProduct.nameEn.indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1
  } )

        

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    
  products: state.categoryReducer.products
    
    
  }

}
```

.........

```
export default  connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ProductsList);
```

Comment: Does "itemProduct" have the "nameEn" property?

Comment: If nameEn is undefined, you can check before trying to do indexOf.
`return  itemProduct.nameEn && itemProduct.nameEn.indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1`

Comment: Yes it is an array of objects fetching it from server api by axios it has nameEn property